# MulterError node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I am trying to upload an image to the database and then display it on the website

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
 const multer = require('multer');
 const dbName = "cars";
 const collectionName = "car-name";


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'C:/Users/tahaa/OneDrive/Desktop/yourcar edit/front-end/src/cars/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  const carImg = req.file.path;
  const carName = req.body.carName;
  const carType = req.body.carType;
  const carYear = req.body.carYear;
  const carColor = req.body.carColor;
  const carDescription = req.body.carDescription;
  const carPrice = req.body.carPrice;
  const carKm = req.body.carKm;

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((client) => {
      const db = client.db(dbName);
      const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
      const myobj = {
        carImg: carImg,
        carName: carName,
        carType: carType,
        carYear: carYear,
        carColor: carColor,
        carDescription: carDescription,
        carPrice: carPrice,
        carKm: carKm
      };

      return collection.insertOne(myobj);
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully!' });
      console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Failed to save image path in MongoDB', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to save image path in MongoDB' });
    });
});
```

I checked it in the post man but this error appears

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HeaderParser.cb (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:200:10)
    at SBMH.push (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)
    at Multipart._write (C:\Users\tahaa\OneDrive\Desktop\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
```

1. The MulterError "Unexpected field" suggests that there is a mismatch between the field name specified in the Multer middleware and the field name used in the client request.
2. Make sure that the field name specified in the **`upload.single()`** function call (**`'file'`**) matches the field name used in the client request for file upload.
3. Double-check that you are sending the request with the correct field name and corresponding file data.

Regarding the provided code snippet, it seems to handle file uploads using Multer and store the uploaded files in the specified destination directory. It then connects to a MongoDB database using the MongoClient and inserts the uploaded file information into a collection.

To troubleshoot the issue further, ensure the following:

1. Verify that you are sending the POST request with the correct field name for the file. It should match the name specified in **`upload.single('file')`**.
2. Make sure you include the necessary fields (**`carName`**, **`carType`**, **`carYear`**, etc.) in the request body when testing the endpoint.
3. Check the file destination path specified in **`destination`**. Ensure that the directory exists and the server has permission to write files to it.

If you have reviewed these aspects and the issue persists, please provide additional information about how you are testing the API (e.g., the request body and headers) so that I can assist you further.

Comment: There might be a conflict between the field name given in the Multer middleware and the field name utilised in the client file upload request. Can you please provide the field names.

Comment: I have used postman and put the name file as in backend

Comment: Then can you please add the screenshot of that request with body.

Comment: Do you want a screenshot of the postman?

Comment: yeah, please give that postman screenshot also. May be it's helpful